# Jest filter filter returns 0 matches

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I'm using Jest v26.6.3 and I'm trying to create a filter to programmatically select what tests to run.

I'm following [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--filterfile) on how to setup a filter file, which seems simple enough, but jest returns `Pattern:  - 0 matches` regardless of the pattern I specify.

PS: If I remove the filter from the CLI argument, jest is able to find/run the tests normally.

**filter.js**

```
module.exports = function(testPaths) {
  return {
    filtered: testPaths
  };
};
```

**CLI**

`jest --filter=absolute\path\to\filter.js`

I know it is picking up the file because I console'd `testPaths` and it output  the file paths as expected.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, in case anyone needs it in the future, looks like it's a bug in Jest ([a bug request has been raised](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/13222)).

Jest expects an array of object with the `test` property set (instead of an array of strings as suggested by the docs) to the test file path, like below:

```
module.exports = (testPaths) => {
  return {
    filtered: testPaths.map((test) => ({ test })),
  };
}
```

The above will obviously not filter anything, but you can implement your own rules before the method returns.